# Typescript compilation errors in weird scenarios

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
type MyObject = {
    [index:string]: MyObject | Function | "wtf"
}
```

When I create a variable of this type, it compiles in this basic example:

```
// compiles
const myObj: MyObject = {
    name: "wtf",
};
```

As well as with a nested key - note the nested key is `notName:`, instead of `name:`

```
// compiles
const myObj: MyObject = {
    wrapper: {
        notName: "wtf",
    },
};
```

As soon as I change the nested key to `name:`, it fails to compile:

```
/*
Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Function | MyObject | "wtf"'.
  Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type '"wtf"'

*/
const myObj: MyObject = {
    wrapper: {
        name: "wtf",
    },
};
```

Other weirdness, if I remove `Function` from the union, it compiles:

```
type MyObjectNoFunction = {
    [index:string]: MyObjectNoFunction | "wtf"
}

let myObjNoFn: MyObjectNoFunction = {
    wrapper: {
        name: "wtf"
    }
};
```

Even more weirdness, if I don't include any libs, like es6, in my tsconfig, everything compiles.

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Check out a [full example on github](https://github.com/mcclaskc/wtf-ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's causing TS to get confused, but here's a wild guess: Maybe this is because `Function` has a `name` property in es6, so TypeScript infers that `{ name: "something" }` is an unfinished `Function` type declaration.

In any case, here are a few ways to fix it.

**You can explicitly type the inner object, like this:**

```
type MyObject = {
  [index:string]: MyObject | Function | "wtf"
}

const innerMyObject: MyObject = {
  name: "wtf",
}

const myObj: MyObject = {
  wrapper: innerMyObject,
};
```

**Or you can explicitly type the string literal, like this:**

```
type MyObject = {
  [index:string]: MyObject | Function | "wtf"
}

const myObj: MyObject = {
  wrapper: {
      name: "wtf" as "wtf",
  },
};
```

Comment: Relevant [definition for `Function` in the `lib.es2015.core` library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.1/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L93-L98)

Comment: I like your first solution, that way it's still truly typed, and not just casting.  
  
Do you think this is worth submitting an issue to the typescript repo?

Comment: @mcclaskc yeah, submitting a bug report would be a good idea.

Comment: @thedayturns done. referenced your thought regarding `Function` as well.  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26587